# Validity of the mov command in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I learned in my class that it's not a valid instruction to move a 16-bit register to a 8-bit register. For example this command is not valid:

```
mov al,bx
```

But is there an instruction like this:

```
mov bx,al
```

Or must the sizes of the 2 registers be equal? As in below:

```
mov al,bl        
mov bx,ax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can i write command : mov bx,al

No, but you can do

```
movsx bx,al  ; sign-extend al into bx
             ; the upper half of bx will be filled with the most significant
             ; bit of al. For example 0x40 becomes 0x0040, while 0xC0
             ; becomes 0xFFC0.
```

or

```
movzx bx,al  ; zero-extend al into bx
             ; the upper half of bx will be filled with zeroes
```

and similarly from 16-bit general purpose registers to 32-bit general purpose registers.

Comment: so what u say if i understand i can not write move bx,al ,mov al,bx

Comment: Right. You can use the sx/zx variants for widening moves. There's no narrowing move though, so `mov al,bl` has to be used instead of `mov al,bx` (assuming that you wanted the lower 8 bits of `bx`).